# Is there a reason to use `$(MAKE) target` as a recipe?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am working on a quite complex and somewhat old makefile (so it could have bogotified over time), and notice rules that have this recipe pattern:

```
SUBDIRS = lib1 lib2 lib3

all:    prerequisites
        $(MAKE) subdirs

subdirs: $(SUBDIRS)
# (empty recipe body)
```

Is (or was) there any reason to write the `all` rule in this way, instead of simply

```
all:    prerequisites subdirs
# (empty recipe body)
```

Is there a subtle difference between the two? I am running both with GNU make 4.1, and not seeing any differences.

The makefile is intended for Linux and OS/X, and supposed to support *somewhat* outdated setups, but not very (for one, we require gcc 4.7, which is 3 years old).

Comment: As written, no, there is no difference (although I would make `prerequisites` prerequisites of `subdirs`). But the pattern you describe can serve a purpose, if there is other code in the makefile. For instance, maybe the `prerequisites` recipe constructs a file which the Makefile will incorporate with `include`, and which contains variables which the `subdirs` rule must have *before execution of any rule*. An exotic case, but they happen. But most likely that makefile was simply written by a beginner.

Comment: As a rule, you *should* never use recursive make, since it disallows fine-grained dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are subtle differences, but this is certainly not important, nor intentional, with your specific situation.

Included, but not limited to, here are some minor differences.

**First difference**: gmake has a special feature that defines (if not already done) and increments the variable **MAKELEVEL** at start. So the following two Makefiles have different results:

```
SUBDIRS = lib1 lib2 lib3
all: prerequisites
     $(MAKE) subdirs
subdirs: $(SUBDIRS)
lib3:
     echo $(MAKELEVEL)
```

Running this Makefile displays:

```
 1
```

But with the following:

```
SUBDIRS = lib1 lib2 lib3
all: prerequisites subdirs
subdirs: $(SUBDIRS)
lib3:
     echo $(MAKELEVEL)
```

Running this Makefile displays:

```
 0
```

So, in case MAKELEVEL would be used in your Makefile, things may not be built the same way. For instance, defining a variable this way would have some impacts:

```
 ifeq (1,${MAKELEVEL})
 CFLAGS=-g
 endif
```

**2nd difference:** as stated in the gmake manual, *By default, only variables that came from the environment or the command line are passed to recursive invocations*. But it would be very rare to have an impact, because if the definition of the variable were not context-dependent, the variable would then be defined with the same value in the inner invocation (to get an impact, you should set a context-dependent variable and encounter different contexts while first running the Makefile and while running the recursive invocation).

**Anyway, people often use recursive invocations when there are other Makefiles in subdirectories** (but this is obviously not your situation). So, we often encounter this:

```
SUBDIRS = lib1 lib2 lib3
all:    prerequisites
     $(MAKE) -C subdirs
```

Of course, this can not be replaced by `all: prerequisites $SUBDIRS`, this would have no sense. **But this is perhaps the reason why somebody wrote what you encountered and not the other way without inner invocation**, thinking wrongly that it is a more common way to write things.

Answer (score 3):

There is one massive and important difference:
Writing it as three separate targets allows the `-j` flag to work properly. `make -j9` tells make to keep 9 jobs running simultaneously, very nice if you have 8 CPUs.

This is a good test of any makefile, and the whole point of *make* IMHO.

The pattern you present is trying to ensure *prerequisites* are complete before the *subdirs* start building. There is a more straight-forward way of writing that of course:

```
all: ${SUBDIRS}
    echo $@ Success

${SUBDIRS}: prerequisites
    echo Building $@...

subdirs: ${SUBDIRS} ; # Empty symbolic target
```

The *subdirs* target is only there as a convenience to anyone who wishes to type `make subdirs`.

`PHONY:` should be added as appropriate of course

Comment: Except that make detects when it runs itself, so the sub-make still interacts with the main jobserver.